# date-fns startOfMonth gives me the previous day

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm trying to use `date-fns` to find the beginning of the current month for a calendar-style app. However, I'm not getting the expected results from `startOfMonth`:

```js
const now = new Date()
const start = startOfMonth(now)
console.log({
  now: now.toISOString(),
  start: start.toISOString()
})
```

Gives:

```json
{
  now: '2023-09-06T18:46:06.795Z', 
  start: '2023-08-31T22:00:00.000Z'
}
```

It's giving me the previous day to the start of the month, at 22h. This points to timezones being the issue, since I'm on GMT+2.

I think my usage is what any developer would expect to do, and I don't see anything in the documentation warning about these. Since `date-fns` is used by thousands of developers in all timezones, is there some common knowledge I'm missing about how to use this?

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you print your dates in ISO format, which does not use your locale, but GMT+00. You shouldn't convert the dates to string in your data structure, unless you need to serialize, but then don't "look" at them until you have deserialized them again.

Answer (score 0):

```
const now = new Date();
const tz = 'Europe/Belgrade';
const zonedNow = utcToZonedTime(now, tz);
const start = startOfMonth(zonedNow);

console.log({
  now: zonedNow.toISOString(),
  start: start.toISOString()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this fixed nothing, I still get a month that starts at 22:00:

`{ now: '2023-09-12T14:37:26.868Z', start: '2023-08-31T22:00:00.000Z' }`

Answer (score 0):

Easy one would be:

```
const startOfMonth = new Date("2023-09-12T14:37:26.868Z");
startOfMonth.setUTCDate(1);
startOfMonth.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```